# How can I execute database commands on the server as a plugin?

Tags: java, orientdb

When extending the server as a plugin, is there a way I can interact with ODocuments without using a database pool to connect to it as if I were a client?

In essence, I do not want to do this:

```
 pool = new OPartitionedDatabasePool(url, user, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try embedding an OrientDB Server inside a Java application.

For detailed information see [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Embedded-Server.html).